# Sometimes zooming with the mousewheel becomes very slow

Tags: 3d-view

I don't know what causes it, but sometimes zooming with the mouse wheel in the 3D View becomes very very slow. When I create a new 3D View it's back at normal speed, restarting Blender doesn't help though.

What could cause this and how can I solve it?

Comment: https://chiaroscorner.wordpress.com/2019/08/18/how-to-fix-slow-zoom-speed-in-blender-2-8/comment-page-1/ try this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The more you zoom in, the slower it becomes. This feature helps with precision zooming when very close to something.

**Here's what you should do:**

Instead of zooming in to something while you (the viewport camera) are very far from it, select that thing whether it is an object, vertex, edge, face, or whatever then press  <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> . This will take you closer to the object, then you can zoom in from there.

Always think of the viewport camera as an actual camera. When you want to take an image of something small, you don't stand very far from it and zoom in, but you get as close to it as possible then take the image.

Comment: For those without a numpad: Press `F3` to bring up the command search and search for `View -> Frame Selected`.

Comment: my FN key is broken :[ is there a way to cancel this behaviour?

Comment: @FilipHedman is the real MVP here. You can also just open the View menu and click Frame Selected.